# Nth digit from Most significant digit side

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, numbers

I want to write a function `int returnNthDigit(long long int number, int position) {}` such that it returns the Nth position digit from the left side. e.g. `returnNthDigit(45006, 1);` must return 4. Similarly, `returnNthDigit(45006, 2);` must return 5. I am not allowed to use any looping statement. Here is one solution I came up with by using loops.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

int returnNthDigit(long long int number, int position)
{
    int numberOfDigits = log10(number) + 1;
    int iteration = numberOfDigits - position;
    while (iteration != 0)
    {
        number = number / 10;
        --iteration;
    }
    return number % 10;
}

int main() {
    std:: ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std:: cout << returnNthDigit(230045, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

Can I do better?

Comment: if you can't use loop, you have to use recursion.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what counts as a `loop`? Because we can do recursion or convert the number to string and do a charAt().

Comment: instead of using while loop, you can replace loop with below                        
                      number = number / pow(10,(numberOfDigits - position));

Comment: If you're allowed to know the size of the `long long int` you could do a "unrolled" binary chop to find the number of digits (which appears to be the tricky bit).  Then a table of powers of 10 to do the extraction.  (What about -ve values, BTW ?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're allowed to use log/pow functions, you're close.
Consider the input 123:

```cpp
int log_base10 = log10(number); // returns 2;
int divide_by = pow(10, log_base10 - index - 1); // returns 10 if index == 2;
int answer = (number/divide_by) % 10;  // returns 2;
```

Be careful with log and pow though, because you are converting from floating points to integers.

You're essentially "chopping" off the lower most digits, and then inspecting the least significant digit with the `% 10` operation.

If you can use strings, it's simpler:

```cpp
auto str = std::to_string(number);
int answer = str[position-1] - '0';
```

Comment: What is the time complexity of `pow()` function in CPP?

Comment: Curious to know if `pow()` gets the value without looping? Is it some bit shifting hack?